# Providing input for additional authentication using Plink

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, putty, plink

After logging into the Unix server, it again asks for user's id. I am not able to pass that userid using Plink from JavaScript file. I need to call a shell script placed in the Unix server after logging into the server. Can any one Please help me.

The code looks as below

```
Plink -l usernameforserverlogin -pw passwrdforserverlogin -batch servername shellscript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Plink is a console application. So you can use input redirection to provide an input:

```
echo userid | plink -l username -pw password -batch host shellscript.sh
```